# Subscription status still "ACTIVE" after a refund

Tags: paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

In my application. I check for each active subscription once a day to check if they are still valid (I do not use Webhooks, simply a Homemade loop script).

I can successfully retrieve if a Subscription is Cancelled (by the Buyer, or the seller), if a subscription is expired or suspended.

But nothing can tell me if a subscription has been refunded or not. Is there a way to know that type of information by the Paypal REST API ?

Apparently I can't Cancel a subscription after a refund. Is this a bug ? A bad design from paypal ? or did I miss something ?

Comment: you should use webhook because it is the right way to know any kind of event takes place, are you using REST?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found why. A refund only concern a certain payment, not the subscription itself. I just have to get the Subscription-ID, get the last payment of that same subscription, and check his status. The payment can have the refund status. Then I just have to Cancel the subscription if I encounter this status, Done.